# IIS make URL Rewrite greedy

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, greedy

I would like to make a generic URL Rewrite rule in IIS 7.5 (on Windows Web Server 2008 R2).

I would like to match the following url's:

www.mysite.com/param
www.mysite.com/folder1/
www.mysite.com/folder1/param
www.mysite.com/folder1/folder2/
www.mysite.com/folder1/folder2/param

Notice the trailing slash (/) when I would like to match a folder, otherwise it is a parameter.

I have set up the following rewrite rule:

```
^(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?([^/]+)?$
```

It has three matching clauses: {R:1}, {R:2} and {R:3}. However, when I input the following test-URL:

**folder1/param**

I get the following response:

{R:1} is empty
{R:2} = folder1
{R:3} = param

I suspected the following response:

{R:1} = folder1
{R:2} is empty
{R:3} = param

I.e. I want **folder1** to be mapped to the first part of the rewrite pattern.

I would like to map the rewrite rule to:

```
/controller.php?folder1={R:1}&folder2={R:2}&param={R:3}
```

What am I missing to get the match to be greedy, i.e. match the first possible clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to make the optional quantifier ("?") greedy in IIS. But I would try to **make the match unambigous**, by enclosing the second optional clause inside the first.

So instead of having the first two options side-by-side as in your original trial:

```
^(?:([^/]+)/)?(?:([^/]+)/)?([^/]+)?$
```

I suggest this:

```
^(?:([^/]+)/(?:([^/]+)/)?)?([^/]+)?$
```

Now the second group can only match if the first did match.

Comment: This works. I didn't want to go to this step, because my actual problem have 4 levels (not just the two provided in the question to examplify the problem), but nevertheless, this seems like a good solution.